# The drop event is not adding the file to the event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code:

```
        $("#dropZone").on("dragover", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();  
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(this).find(".panel-body h3").html("Drop file now");
        });

        $("#dropZone").on("dragleave", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();  
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(this).find(".panel-body h3").html("Drop file here");
        });

        $("#dropZone").on("drop", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            console.log(event.originalEvent.dataTransfer);
        });
```

However, when I look at the event that I log in the last piece of code the file is not in it, even though it raised the event.

[image: Screenshot]

I put up my code in a jsfiddle, please have a look:
https://jsfiddle.net/kd75vj5e/

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but what is it that you are dragging and dropping?

Comment: @Culme Files  (Dave figured out the problem already though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Chrome? If so, this is a bug with the console.

`console.log(event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);`. Your code is fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/kd75vj5e/1/

IE doesn't seem to work with your code sample. I can't test in Firefox at the moment.

Comment: My code is fine but it doesn't work in IE?! That is horrifying, I use OS X so I can't test that. But yes, you are right I see now that it's a problem with the console :/